# Magento 1.9.2.4 sending to multiple people

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, invoice

I have a customer i do marketing for and all of the sudden magento ver 1.9.2.4 started to send the first invoice to the customer and two other customers? These are different people each time. Have you come across this?

Thanks